# Handle multiple exceptions in Kotlin Kotest eventually

Tags: kotlin, generics, exception, kotlin-multiplatform, kotest

As per kotest docs: https://github.com/kotest/kotest/blob/master/doc/nondeterministic.md

> You can tell `eventually` to ignore specific exceptions and any others will immediately fail the test.

I want to pass multiple exceptions to eventually that I know would be thrown by my block so that I can explicitly skip them.

Right now I only see a way to pass one, how do I pass more than one exception to `eventually` to skip it in case the block throws those exceptions?

Comment: https://github.com/kotest/kotest/issues/2207

Answer (score 1):

The module [kotest-framework-concurrency](https://kotest.io/docs/framework/concurrency/eventually.html) contains an `eventually` that allows to specify multiple suppressed exceptions.

There is the possibility to specify a set of exception types:

```kotlin
eventually({
  duration = 8000
  suppressExceptions = setOf(UserNotFoundException::class)
}) {
  userRepository.getById(1).name shouldNotBe "bob"
}
```

And, there is the possibility to specify a predicate for exceptions:

```kotlin
eventually({
  duration = 8000
  suppressExceptionIf = { it is UserNotFoundException && it.username == "bob" }
}) {
  userRepository.getById(1).name shouldNotBe "bob"
}
```

Alternatively, you can specify when the test is considered to be in the state that a failure can actually be regarded as failure:

```kotlin
var string = "x"
eventually({
  duration = 5.seconds()
  predicate = { it.result == "xxx" }
}) {
  string += "x"
  string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use superclass for all your exceptions like

```
eventually(200.milliseconds, exceptionClass = RuntimeException::class) {
   throw IllegalStateException()
}
```

or wrap exceptions

```
eventually(200.milliseconds, exceptionClass = IllegalStateException::class) {
    runCatching { throw UnknownError() }
        .onFailure { throw IllegalStateException(it) }
}
```

In `4.4.3` there are no features with collection of Exception